# FluentNHibernate: how to Join to table without using primary key

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

In the following FluentNHibernate mapping:

```
public LawbaseAssetMap()
{
  Table("PRASSET");
  Id(x => x.Id).Column("PRA_RECNUM");   
  Join("PRSTOCK", m =>
  {
    m.Fetch.Join();
    m.Optional();
    m.KeyColumn("PRS_ASSRN");
    m.Map(t => t.Certificated).Column("PRS_CERT").CustomType("YesNo");
  });
}
```

I am performing an outer join from the table `PRASSET` to the table `PRSTOCK`. The join is between `PRSTOCK.PRS_ASSRN` and `PRASSET.PRA_RECNUM` (the primary key of `PRASSET`).

How would I create the equivalent join, but instead of joining onto `PRASSET`'s primary key, join on to another field instead?

Comment: Looks like this is a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442611/fluent-nhibernate-join-not-using-primary-key I was hoping for a better answer than References too :/

Comment: David, I have the same problem, so could you share the solution or workaround for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

David have a look on following link, as i thing that it might help

[Fluent NHibernate - Mapping a property to a column on a joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188108/fluent-nhibernate-mapping-a-property-to-a-column-on-a-joined-table)

also this might help

```
ReferencesAny(x => x.Author)
  .EntityTypeColumn("Type")
  .EntityIdentifierColumn("Id")
  .IdentityType<int>();
```

See more here.

Hope this helps... and now really holliday :) see u